# How does performance differ between a volatile Excel function and a VBA UDF that uses evaluate() on it?

Tags: excel, vba, performance, user-defined-functions

I have an unusual use case -- we have a table of calculation rules and another table that looks up that table in order to make calculations. So we do an XLOOKUP that returns a formula, and then we execute the formula.

For example, I have a VBA UDF called execute_formula()

```
Function Execute_Formula(Formula As String)

Execute_Formula = Evaluate(Formula)

End Function
```

How would I see how much slower Execute_Formula("A1") is than INDIRECT("A1")?

Comment: FYI `Application.Evaluate(Formula)` will always use the context of the active sheet - that may or may not be the context you want, so it's good to use the worksheet version of Evaluate - `worksheetReference.Evaluate(formulaHere)` to make sure it's doing what you want.

Comment: Volatile functions are not in themselves slow to use.  The problem with volatile functions is that they recalculate every time there is a change on any open excel workbook.  Normal Functions do not recalculate unless the predecessors change.  Thus regular non volatile function do not need to recalc as often.  Your UDF will only recalculate if the string changes.  If the string does not change but the data to which the string formula references changes it will  not recalculate, unless you make it volatile.    So if your string formula is `=SUM(A:A)` if A:A changes it will not recalc.

Comment: Another thing to remember is that INDIRECT will only return a valid range reference.  You cannot do `=INDIRECT("SUM(A:A)")` where this UDF will do it: `=Execute_Formula("SUM(A:A)")`  So basically there are pros and cons to either approach.